# issue regarding re direct from aspx page to mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have used PostBackUrl(url) to re direct from aspx to mvc page .
Because 
my aspx and mvc projects are on different domain.

its getting redirected but I have to refresh the page to go to "url".

Please give me some solution on how to re direct from aspx to mvc page 
which are in different domain

Comment: how to redirect to external url from .cs file

Comment: postBackUrl("htttp://google.com") is working

Comment: but when i do postbackUrl("localhost/CallOut/Index") in .cs file to redirect to mvc page   ,,,,it does not work somehow

Comment: try Response.Redirect